# how to use angular pipe and subscribe correctly in request call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular application I am sending a request to my backend to check credentials, after success the backend sends an token which I read. So far this works, but I had to use an pipe to make it map to a method and then make it work. But my problem now it even though I am getting 200 from the server my page will not navigate to the protected page automatically. If I enter the url manually it works this is what I tried:

```
  authenticateUser(login: LoginModel){
    this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler)
    return this.http.post<JwtToken>(environment.rootUrl + 'api/authenticate', {
      username: login.username,
      password: login.password,
    }).pipe(map(response => this.authenticateSuccess(response)))
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
        }, error: (error) => {
          this.isAuthenticated = false;
          console.log(error)
        }
      })

  }
```

It does not enter the subscribe part after the pipe. Is there any way to make this work? I still want to have an error handling like if no error then navigate to url if error do not navigate.

EDIT:

AuthenticateSuccess method:

```
  isUserLoggedIn(){
    return !! localStorage.getItem('authenticationToken')
  }

  private authenticateSuccess(response: JwtToken): void {
      const jwt = response.id_token;
      localStorage.setItem('authenticationToken' , jwt)
      this.localStorageService.store('authenticationToken', jwt);
      console.log(this.localStorageService.retrieve('authenticationToken'))
      this.sessionStorageService.clear('authenticationToken');

  }
```

Authguard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['authenticate'])
        resolve(false)
      }
    })

  }
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
 authenticateUser(login: LoginModel) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler)
    return this.http.post<JwtToken>(environment.rootUrl + 'api/authenticate', {
      username: login.username,
      password: login.password,
    }).subscribe({
      next: response => {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.authenticateSuccess(response)
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
      }, error: (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }, complete: () => {
        console.log("finished without worry")
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: post also the code for `authenticateSuccess`

Comment: I did and also the authguard and the method from the service it calls on "isUserLoggedIn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJs `map` operator is supposed to modify the content of an observable. The `map` operator however needs to return the same observable or another observable, for the next `subscribe` operation to be able to function.

In your case your `map` operator does not return any observable at all and therefore the `subscribe` method has no reason to be triggered.

You could simple return the `response` again in your method here

```
private authenticateSuccess(response: JwtToken): any {
      const jwt = response.id_token;
      localStorage.setItem('authenticationToken' , jwt)
      this.localStorageService.store('authenticationToken', jwt);
      console.log(this.localStorageService.retrieve('authenticationToken'))
      this.sessionStorageService.clear('authenticationToken');
      return response;
  }
```

but I think all the code of the `map` method matches better directly inside the `subscribe` method.

Comment: Thanks it worked, just like you said I have put the code inside the pipe and map into subsription. I will post the final code in a bit